# Simple Laravel public function (if/else) for substr method

Tags: php, laravel, function, public

I have a table in my page with 6 columns and I need some help for the last one called Notes(Description). Here, I'm using the tooltip for showing the description above because usually the text is very long and for the column text I used substr($item->notes, 0, 15) to catch only the first 15 letters.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to make a function in my model, to serve me with the next behavior: if the item has a description, then show the substr($item->notes, 0, 15), else show only 'N/A'.

Here's my entry in view:

```
<td class="text-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="{{ $item->notes ? $item->notes : 'N/A'  }}">{{ substr($item->notes, 0, 15) }}</td>
```

Comment: and your if statement is where?

Comment: He wants to recreate this function in his model. You might want to take a look in this topic https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eloquent-relationships-and-substring (the same problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the helper functions of laravel, in this case, str_limit () would serve you, for example:

```
<td class="text-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="{{ $item->notes ? $item->notes : 'N/A'  }}">
    {{ str_limit($item->notes, 15) }}
</td>
```

In addition laravel has many more useful functions, you can see them in the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-limit

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers

Now if you need to create your own functions here explain a way how to do it:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

> To define an accessor, create a **getFooAttribute** method on your model
>   where **Foo** is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access.
>   In this example, we'll define an accessor for the  **first_name**
>   attribute. The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when
>   attempting to retrieve the value of the **first_name** attribute:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

In your case that would result in something similar like

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['notes']; // just for this demo

    public function getNotesAttribute($value)
    {
        if (!empty($value)) {
            return substr($value, 0, 15);
        } else{
            return 'N/A';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply do $item->notes in your view without having to write the condition every time, you will have to use an accessor in your model.

Here, I am assuming "notes" is the name of your despription property. Modify it to suit your needs.

```
public function getNotesAttribute($value) {
      if (!empty($value)) {
        return substr($value, 0, 15);
      } else{
        return 'N/A';
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I might use it on other cases and I'll keep it in mind. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the same as you have done in the title:

```
<td class="text-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="{{ $item->notes ? $item->notes : 'N/A'  }}">{{ substr($item->notes, 0, 15) ? substr($item->notes, 0, 15) : 'N/A' }}</td>
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it won't work like that unfortunately.